# How to convert a text file by word2vec using python

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, nlp, glove

I am beginner of python language,natural language processing,deep learning,neural networks.I want to execute a program which convert text file into vector by using word2vec in python..someone please help me

```
import math 
import nltk file = "/home/stephy/Demo/textfile.txt" 
import numpy as np 

def loadGloveModel(gloveFile): 
    with open(gloveFile, encoding="utf8" ) as f: 
        content = f.readlines() 
    model = {} for line in content: 
        splitLine = line.split() 
        word = splitLine[0] 
    embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]])  
    model[word] = embedding 
    print ("Done.",len(model)," words loaded!") 
    return model 

model= loadGloveModel(file) 
print (model['file'])
```

Comment: Show what you've tried and where you've having a problem.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer import math
import nltk
file = "/home/stephy/Demo/textfile.txt"
import numpy as np
def loadGloveModel(gloveFile):
    print ("Loading Glove Model")
    with open(gloveFile, encoding="utf8" ) as f:
       content = f.readlines()
    model = {}
    for line in content:
        splitLine = line.split()
        word = splitLine[0]
        embedding = np.array([float(val) for val in splitLine[1:]])
        model[word] = embedding
    print ("Done.",len(model)," words loaded!")
    return model
model= loadGloveModel(file)
print (model['file'])

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and don't know the exact formatting of the code. Sorry for the excuse

Comment: Please recheck if code is added correctly to your post. Btw: In the editor there is a button with curly brackets. Simply paste your code, activate it and press the button. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting